# Google cloud platform php file shows 404 error after deploying it

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to create a very simple php mysql webpage (search a db and show result) in google cloud platform. Have tried many times using the hello world application but can't make it through. Can anyone help please ? 
I created an App Engine project in the process. Created the Cloud sql instance. But after that I am lost, how do I upload simple php file to work here ?
Any suggestion or guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try another tutorial maybe?

Comment: have you followed this tutorial? https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/hello-world#hello_world_code_review

Comment: Yes I started with this, it run well. But did not work when I tried to deploy with my simple html codes in php file

Comment: Try to figure out the file locations on your server